# Ошибка «No SLF4J providers were found» при установке SLF4J в Maven

Tags: java, maven, логирование, slf4j

Пытаюсь через Maven подключить это логирование!

Вот мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>projekt1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Вылетает постоянно эта ошибка:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
```

Может что то еще нужно подключить помимо в Maven?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сообщении об ошибке дается ссылка на документацию: http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders

Там написано, что нужно обязательно подключить реализацию логгера:

> Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

Раз у Вас уже используется log4j-api, то, думаю, нужно добавить зависимость slf4j-log4j12 в POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

Для того чтобы работал log4j нужно будет создать файл конфигурации (log4j.properties).

Comment: Добавил, теперь это выдает:                                                                                                                                  log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (Test).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Comment: @P.Vlasov Почитайте по ссылке. Там как раз говорится о том что нужен файл log4j.properties.